# jQuery resize event handler not working on DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize, height

I am trying to get a divider to resize when another divider resizes due to content being loaded into it. When I bind the resize event handler onto the divider which loads the content, when it's loaded and the divider stretches to fit it in, the event is never called. Is this because no explicit "height" property is set on the divider through CSS?

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/q2pJ9/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <button>Click me</button>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="other_container">
    <p>Will appear when "container" extends.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content{
    display:none;
    height: 200px;
    background: grey;
}
.other_container{
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".content").slideToggle();
});
$(".container").resize(function(){
    $(".other_container").fadeIn();
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'll try and make a jsfiddle to show you, my code is quite long.

Comment: As far as I know, the resize event is not called on `<div>`s. Only on `window` elements.

Comment: Yep, `resize` is only supported for `window`.

Comment: Is there a workaround / plugin which allows this that you know of? Thanks

Comment: http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/ ?

Comment: @StefanDunn how about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LTQ5G/1/)?

Comment: I ended up using this plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: The jQuery docs imply you can set this handler on any element, not just window. I've reported a documentation bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I really understand but you will something like that?

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $(".content").slideToggle(1500 , function(){
      $(".other_container").fadeIn();
   });
});
```

link to the example http://jsfiddle.net/q2pJ9/6/

Comment: The only thing is that the container divider could expand from more than one button. Thus instead of adding repeated code, I thought a listener for the change in side would be more appropriate. I have managed to use this plugin to get it to work: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/